# NSFetchedResultsController - how to handle changing Core Data source?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I'm using Core Data with MagicalRecord and `NSFetchedResultsController` to display data in a table view. Everything works fine, now I have to change the underlying sqlite-file underneath which leads to a crash.

I'm creating the FRC the following way:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"CDPerson"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByNameDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = @[sortByNameDescriptor];
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
[_fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
```

When changing the sqlite-file, I'm doing:

```
[MagicalRecord cleanup];
// delete old sqlite file
// copy new sqlite file
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:SQLITE_FILENAME];
```

What do I have to do with my FRC to have it take the new storage? Only create a new one seems not enough as I get a crash in

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

@question from flexaddicted: The error I'm getting in endUpdates is `Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]`

@question from Exploring: you can imagine that I've got two sqlite files which I'm exchanging - both with the same tables, but different content. The FRC shows the content of the first file, now I'd like cleanUp MagicalRecord, let it point to the other store and 'refresh' the FRC.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with *now I have to change the underlying sqlite-file underneath which leads to a crash*? What's the crash?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the underlying sqlite-file"?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to tear everything down and restart. Once you have recreated the Core Data stack you need to recreate the FRC with the new context and `reloadData` on the table view (you can't just reload some rows because the backing data has completely changed).